# A Strange Safari

Tags: visual, steganography, animals

Well, my friend told me that he's just visited a safari. Being toured around, he was very surprised how the guide could spot those animals so quickly.

He took some pictures of the animals, anticipating to show them to me. However, when he gave me the photos, the photos are nothing like animals!

Where on earth are they?

The photos (spoilered as surprise):

> [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> There's something in each picture that contains the name of an animal.
>
>  1. flag**bear**er
>  2. certifi**cat**e
>  3. **inca**ndescent light bulb
>  4. c**rat**e
>  5. chrys**ant**hemum / chrysanth**emu**m
>  6. s**pig**ot
>  7. **boar**d
>  8. cup**bear**er
>  9. mi**crow**ave
>  10. **pup**pet
>  11. **carp**et
>  12. t**ant**rum

Comment: nailed logic, but 3 words need to be adjusted...

Comment: needa hint? 1. one typo found among the words. 2. no duplicate animals

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I'm guessing the incorrect ones are 1, 3 and 12.

Comment: yep, it's those 3, and there's an additional typo in another one

Comment: typo: crysant**h**emum, and supposed animal was e??, but both would work

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Aaaa I see

Comment: I always thought it was [**chrys**anthemum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysanthemum), for what it’s worth...

Comment: @El-Guest In my defence, it's not the easiest word to spell :P

Comment: Definitely the hardest one up there! I thought your 1 and 12 were pretty good LOL @jafe